# BASH Convert columns to rows with labels

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to process a file content using bash.

Assume the content is made up by labels and elements, such as:

```
A 1,2,3,4
B 5
```

Now it needs to be converted to:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 5
```

I tried `sed` to insert newline every n characters but I cannot insert labels to new lines and it is not seperated as expected.

```
sed -e "s/.\{3\}/&\n/g" < test.txt
```

result:

```
A 1
,2,
3,4

B 8
```

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
awk -F "[ ,]" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print $1, $i}' i.txt
```

Output:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question... The file has 2 lines but there is only 1 loop. When the loop finishes processing on the first line, how could it know there are rest lines in this file to be processed?